# Assign a unique cluster based on a dataframe column with KMeans Algorithm

Tags: python, clustering, pandas, k-means, numpy

I have the following `df`

```
    x1      x2    x3   x4     
   1000   5000    0.8  restaurant1
   2000   7000   0.75  restaurant1
    500   1000    0.5  restaurant2
    700   1400    0.6  restaurant2
   1000   5000    0.8  restaurant2
    100    600    0.9  restaurant3
    200   1200    0.9  restaurant3
     50   1000    0.9  restaurant3
```

applying a Kmeans Algorithm for 2 clusters what happens is that `y`:

```
    x1      x2    x3   x4             Y
   1000   5000    0.8  restaurant1    1
   2000   7000   0.75  restaurant1    1   
    500   1000    0.5  restaurant2    2
    700   1400    0.6  restaurant2    2
   1000   5000    0.8  restaurant2    1
    100    600    0.9  restaurant3    2
    200   1200    0.9  restaurant3    2
     50   1000    0.9  restaurant3    2
```

Possible Desired Outputs:

```
     x1      x2    x3   x4             Y
    1000   5000    0.8  restaurant1    1
    2000   7000   0.75  restaurant1    1   
     500   1000    0.5  restaurant2    2
     700   1400    0.6  restaurant2    2
    1000   5000    0.8  restaurant2    2
     100    600    0.9  restaurant3    2
     200   1200    0.9  restaurant3    2
      50   1000    0.9  restaurant3    2
```

or

```
     x1      x2    x3   x4             Y
    1000   5000    0.8  restaurant1    1
    2000   7000   0.75  restaurant1    1   
     500   1000    0.5  restaurant2    1
     700   1400    0.6  restaurant2    1
    1000   5000    0.8  restaurant2    1
     100    600    0.9  restaurant3    2
     200   1200    0.9  restaurant3    2
      50   1000    0.9  restaurant3    2
```

I would like to set this boundary: a restaurant must belong to 1 and only 1 cluster.

I understand why there is this output, but how could I avoid and fix it?

Below the code that I used in my notebook:

```
  #Converting float64 to numpy array 
  x1=df['x1'].to_numpy()
  x2=df['x2'].to_numpy()
  x3=(df['x5']/df['x2']).to_numpy()
  x4=df_joint_raw['x4'].cat.codes.to_numpy()

  X=np.stack((x1,x2,x3,x4),axis=1)
  #Getting clusters
  y_pred=KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit_predict(X)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting question! I try my best:

It depends a bit on the number of clusters and number of restaurant but in general I explain a bit.

If the number of restaurants and clusters are the same, then, theoretically, your question has just one [trivial answer](https://www.mathwords.com/t/trivial.htm): *"each restaurant is a cluster"*. You even don't need any algorithm. I go a bit deeper on it.

Most of ML algorithms solve an optimization problem to find the answer. Sometimes optimization problems are subject to some constraints.

**Example**:

1. Cluster restaurants such that all similar restaurants **are necessarily assigned** to the same cluster.
2. Cluster restaurants such that the density of same restaurants in same clusters **is maximum**.

The first one has the trivial answer I gave before but second one can be solved. You run several clustering methods (or just k-means but with several initial conditions) and accept the one in which higher number of similar restaurants are in identical clusters. For this you need to convert *"density of same restaurants in same clusters"* to a mathematical formulation and use it as criterion of choice. If you need help on it just drop a comment so I update the answer.

In any case, you change the output of the clustering and you don't let it "naturally" find the clusters as you push a criterion which is not normally considered in the algorithm. But don't worry! The good thing is that at least you have a criterion for "goodness" of your clustering which does not exist normally in clustering problem.

### UPDATE

Let's try [$\chi^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) test first. It is pretty simplified but try it and if it didn't work we can think of something else. For know how, I prepared it for you in a simple way so you don't get confused with different tutorials on the net.

Imagine you have 4 restaurants and you want 4 clusters. You will end up with such a frequency table which says how many restaurants of which type fall in which cluster:

[image]

Then in Python, you simply calculate $\chi^2$ statistic which tells you if clusters and restaurants "are correlated or not".

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
obs = np.array([[10,1,2,1], [1,11,0,1], [1,2,8,1], [0,2,2,12]])
chi, p, _,_ = chi2_contingency(obs)
print('The chi-square statistic of {} with p-value of {}'.format(chi,p))
```

P-value, as you know, tells you if the statistic is significant. There theoretical consideration in this solution but I am not going to confuse you with that. I apologize as I did not go through your proposal in the comment. Will answer accordingly as soon as I find time to have a look at that.

Good Luck!

Comment: Clear for the trivial one. The second one is really interesting and I will really appreciate the mathematical formulation (also Python code because I don't know how to implement otherwise). One tactic that I implemented similar to point 1is to understand what happens if a do the average on all the possible cluster value assumed by my restaurant Kmeans Output ex. rest 2,1 -> Cluster 2 rest2,2->Cluster2 rest 1,3 ->Cluster1 This way I could have a "frequentist" interpretation of my restaurant "Usually behaves like all restaurant in cluster 2, sometimes like cluster 1"

Comment: The second tactic that I adopted It is to average the input data and getting a unique cluster for each restaurant.